# Howto: Parallel.Foreach executes many processes, after each process run a new process (but one at a time)?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, parallel.foreach

I'm sure someone knows this and I will be very thankful for the answer. I don't know much about delegates and asynch and the like - so please give me a general example of how I could implement.

I have a workflow where 
   I can use Parallel.Foreach to execute a method for many different files at the same time (sweet, grind that processor) - 
   however after that method ends I need to run another method (it generates a report on the previous process), 
      and this second method cannot be run in parallel.

I don't want to wait for all the files in the Parallel.ForEach to finish before generating reports (that's not necessary). But if I start the report generation method as the first method ends then I run into problems. Is there some kind of queue or something? There's gotta be some pretty way of doing it, right?

Thanks

Comment: So when would you like the report generation to start? Is it that you want to queue results from the foreach until you reach a specific threshold then start on the report?

Comment: Immediately following execution of the first method on a file, then I want to start executing the second method - however the second method can only process one 'file' at a time. So MANY processes running, one of the MANY finishes, start report, another of the MANY processes finishes, wait for first report then start 2nd report generation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually executing a method/function that starts a process(another application), but that's a whole bag of confusing semantics.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the title/question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what Jim G means is:

```
var lockObj = new object();

Parallel.Foreach(files, file => 
{
    // Processing file
    lock(lockObj)
    {
        // Generate report.
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, this worked perfect. Interesting, I'm not sure I intuit this fully (is intuit a word or can it be used like that, I feel smart...or stupid)  Anyway, thanks I'll try to understand this as well as the Arbiter.Interleave which seems to be quite powerful a tool.

Answer (score 1):

The second method should be chained as a [continuation task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx).

Within the second method, use a [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or mutex to ensure that it does not run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The [Arbiter.Interleave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.ccr.core.arbiter.interleave.aspx) coordination primitive in the Concurrency and Coordination Runtime (CCR) provides a simple way of achieving the functionality you want. basically you pass it 3 receiver groups 1 for concurrent tasks, 1 for exclusive tasks (not executed in parallel) and 1 for shutting down the entire process. You can find an example of how to use it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648749.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use the producer-consumer model. You have a [thread safe blocking collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312) that you put the finished data in then you have one thread that runs the reports pulling data from that collection.

```
//Collection to hold the data the processed files generated
var proccesedDataItems = new new BlockingCollection<ResultData>();

//A thread that processes the files
var processReports = new Task(() =>
{
    //Removes items from the collection, if the collection is empty it blocks
    // or if "CompletedAdded" has been called it will reach the "end" of the 
    // collection
    foreach(var processedData in proccesedDataItems.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        BuildReport(processedData);
    }
});
processReports.Start();    

//Generating the data
Parallel.Foreach(files, file => 
{
   var proccesedData = ProcessFile(file)
   proccesedDataItems.Add(processedData);
});

//Let anyone consuming the collection that you can stop waiting for new items.
proccesedDataItems.CompleteAdding();
```

Answer (score 1):

Things like this fit nicely into the model of TPL Dataflow: you create one parallel block that processes the files and then another non-parallel block that generates the report:

```
var processFileBlock = new TransformBlock<File, Result>(
    file => ProcessFile(file),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded
    });

var generateReportBlock = new ActionBlock<Result>(
    result => GenerateReport(result));

processFileBlock.LinkTo(generateReportBlock);

foreach (var file in files)
    processFileBlock.Post(file);
```

If you also want to wait until all processing is done, you would need to add some code using `Complete()` and `Completetion`.

Comment: Not sure, but would you need to state max parallelism as 1 on the generateReportBlock?

Comment: @JamesManning You don't need to do that, because 1 is the default.

Comment: Ah, ok - happen to know if/where that's documented?  I didn't see a default mentioned at [the ctor page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194830)

Comment: Ok, found it on [this page for setting max parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609) which states "The first computation specifies a maximum degree of parallelism of 1, which is the default."

Comment: @JamesManning The documentation of TDF is not great at the moment, but [the documentation for `ExcutionDataflowBlockOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions) does say the default is 1. And Stephen Toub's [*Introduction to TPL Dataflow*](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782) says the same thing.