# Parallelism, a few 1000 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

We have a web application that monitors several social media's like twitter/facebook. The data that we receive from these social media's are being saved into the database. The data is big, and for that reason I was thinking about using `Task`'s to save the data into the database.

But I have some concerns about how it works. Can't find in the docs what happens if I start 10 threads for 1 user multiplied by 2000 users? Or maybe 10.000 users.

What exactly will `Task` do? Does it have some sort of queue for these `Threads`?

Any light on this matter would be really appreciated it. Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread

Comment: I had a similar problem and start using a threadpool. See this question/answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954514/usage-multithreading-could-lead-to-excessive-memory-use

Comment: You'll need 1000 cores to run 1000 threads. Anything more than the number of cores on a server, might slow the system down instead of speeding it up.

Comment: @SWeko: That's not true. I have 1650 threads running on my machine and I (sadly) do not have 1650 cores on my CPU. Keep in mind that threads can do more than computation; they can wait for IO or network, just sleep until they are needed, etc. That being said, creating 10k worker threads is very likely a stupid idea and a thread pool works much better.

Comment: I have 1284 :) At best, they waste memory (there is a 1MB minimum) :) However, having a single process with that many threads, would be a red flag.

Comment: You may be better off just using a few dedicated threads (Perhaps [`Parallel.ForEach(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)) and using the [producer consumer model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323940/howto-parallel-foreach-executes-many-processes-after-each-process-run-a-new-pr/12324559#12324559) to queue up the work and let it be processed by the queue.

Comment: @SWeko 1MB is the *default* Windows stack size, but I believe .NET defaults with something much smaller. It is still, of course, a waste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Task` is just a wrapper around a delegate that can be scheduled to the `TaskScheduler`'s queue. `Task` does not create any threads. When you are calling `task.Start()` internally it calls the `taskScheduler.QueueTask(Task)` method.

By default all tasks use the `TaskScheduler.Default` which internally uses the `ThreadPool`. 
You can specify your custom task scheduler when creating `TaskFactory` - this class has a constructor that accepts a `TaskScheduler` parameter. Current scheduller is always available through the `TaskScheduler.Current` property.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) to do this.

By using the APM you can avoid creating hundreds of threads.

Behind the scenes the APM can use [`I/O Completion Ports`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to provide callbacks when data has arrived or been sent, which means a thread doesn't have to be wasted.

See here for some details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh300224.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A `Task` uses a `Thread` to do the work.

`Tasks` are queued to the `ThreadPool`.

To answer your question; you'd need to try it out and see if the application copes.

You could probably share threads so it would not be 10*2000 threads.